# We are trying to find the minimum of a linked list

Tags: java, linked-list, singly-linked-list, minimum

We are practicing for an exam and are trying to find the minimum value of a linked list in java. This algorithm keeps returning the last element of the list instead of the minimum.

```
public class minMax {

    element head;

    public void MinMax(){
        this.head = null;
    }

    public void addElement(element el){
        element reference = this.head;
        this.head = el;
        element nxt = this.head.getNext();
        nxt= reference;
    }

    public int findMin(){
        int min = this.head.getValue();
        element current = this.head;
        while (current != null) {
            if(current.getValue() < min){
                System.out.println("found min");
                min = current.getValue();
            }
            current = current.getNext();
        }
        return min;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        element a = new element(5,null);
        element b = new element(55, null);
        element c = new element(45, null);
        minMax list= new minMax();
        list.addElement(a);
        list.addElement(b);
        list.addElement(c);

        int min = list.findMin();
        System.out.println(min);
    }

}
```

Comment: And did you debug through it?

Comment: https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/

Answer (score 1):

The main problem is with this part:

```
element nxt = this.head.getNext();
nxt= reference;
```

This doesn't change the value of `next` inside `head` in the way that you're expecting. It just makes the `nxt` variable refer to `reference`.

You haven't included the code for your `Element` class, but you probably want to update `next` directly e.g.

```
this.head.setNext(reference);
```

Also this line:

```
public void MinMax() {
```

is not defining a constructor for your class, as you're probably expecting it to because the case of the name `MinMax` is different to the name of the class `minMax`. A constructor also doesn't have a return type so to fix this rename your class `MinMax` (to follow Java naming conventions) and then remove the `void` from the constructor definition.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your **demo**, I just tested it locally and make some modifications.

- Using `Comparable` to enable you to replace the type easily as long as the type implemented the `Comparable` interface (to find the minimum, you have to compare);
- Using `head` as the **sentry** to make the `adding` and `deleting` (if you need to delete) easier;

By the way, in java you'd better use *Uppercase* prefix for the class name, so your class name `element` should be replace by `Element`. And actually you are encapsulating your class in a good way as a beginner.

Here is the code:

```
public class HelloWorld {

    Node head; // not store any value, just used to link the nodes;

    public Comparable findMin() {
        if (head == null || head.next == null) {
            return null;
        }
        Comparable min = head.next.value;
        Node p = head.next.next;
        while(p != null) {
            if (min.compareTo(p.value) > 0) min = p.value;
            p = p.next;
        }
        return min;
    }

    public void add(Node node) {
        if (head == null) {
            head = new Node(null, node);
        } else {
            node.next = head.next;
            head.next = node;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String... args) {
        HelloWorld list = new HelloWorld();
        list.add(new Node(5, null));
        list.add(new Node(45, null));
        list.add(new Node(55, null));
        System.out.println(list.findMin().toString());
    }

    static class Node {
        Comparable value;
        Node next;
        public Node(Comparable theValue, Node theNext) {
            this.value = theValue;
            this.next = theNext;
        }
    }
}
```

The output is working as you expect.

```
5
```

Hope it helps you ~

Comment: You should explain what changes you made.

Comment: Hahah, thanks for the reminder. Actually I was on the way typing them in...bad network made me...